# Observable in a callback function - angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to execute a callback in which only after getting the response it should execute the lines, starting from `this.groupDefaultExpanded = -1;` after that.

```
 loadLoginDetails() {
    this.derivativeSpecService.getDerivativeDetails().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.rowData = res;
            this.groupDefaultExpanded = -1;
            this.getDataPath = function(data) {
              return data.orgHierarchy;
            };
              this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
              headerName: "Name",
            };

            console.log(this.rowData);
        })
      }
```

*derivativespec.ts*

```
 getDerivativeDetails(){

        return this.http.get('assets/derivativespec.json').map((response: Response) => response);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: before getting the response other lines are executed which in turn says undefined. i need to execute other lines only after getting the response successfully.

Comment: The `res` variable is your response ? Can you please share the code of the called method `getDerivativeDetails()` ?

Comment: Try to rephrase the question as is not really clear. When you subscribe you already have your response. If you want to run a callback there just do it as a normal callback...

Comment: yes, res variable is my response. i have updated the above code with getDerivativeDetails().

Comment: This part of the code is not needed `.map((response: Response) => response)`, you can specify your return object type by setting the get generic type `...http.get<Response>(...`. In the function in the subscription is executed, you already have the server response, and the `res` has the server response value. If it is undefined, then maybe the server returns no content. You can debug that in the network tab of your browsers dev tools.

Comment: @ibenjelloun partially true, your answer is correct if he uses HttpClient, not if he uses Http.

Comment: @trichetriche ok forgot to mention that, my bad. Http has been deprecated for nearly a year. I'm maybe optimistic to think no one is using it anymore.

Comment: @ibenjelloun then we should not take IE as an example of old things still being used :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
getDerivativeDetails(): Promise<Response> {
    return this.http.get<Response>('assets/derivativespec.json').toPromise();
}
```

And then:

```
loadLoginDetails() {
    this.derivativeSpecService.getDerivativeDetails().then(
        res => {
            this.rowData = res;
            this.groupDefaultExpanded = -1;
            this.getDataPath = function(data) {
              return data.orgHierarchy;
            };
            this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
              headerName: "Name",
            };

            console.log(this.rowData);
    });
}
```